# Need some way for authentication in iphone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application one requirement is there, in start up i want some authentication, by that in server side i can know who is using that appliation and i can store info of that persern other side.

i know one way of passing device id, but client dont want that way. is thare any other way for check in authenticate ?

If any one know way then please tell me ASAP.

Thank you for reply in addvance

Comment: Instead of asking us, ask the client what he wants.  Does he want the user to enter a username and password?  Does he want the user to have a [SecurID](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1156)-type device?  Does he want something else entirely?

Comment: ohh sry i forgot to tell he dont want username and password. client want some secure id but dont want to pass device id. he want some other way

Comment: The client wants fairies to magically authenticate for him?  If he doesn't like username/password, he needs to suggest an alternative, or at least point to some site/app that uses a mechanism that he does like.

Comment: ya this is the requirement in my project also from the client.

Comment: than you Mr.jason and Mr.rob but client want idea from our side. he is not technical in iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, since the poster doesn't want to use usernames or passwords:

Use public key authentication. It's perfect for your use case, and very secure. Generate a keypair on the device on first launch and then send the public key to the server to register the device. Then whenever you want to authenticate the app's connection to the server, sign your data with your private key and then your server can decrypt it with the public key. Or you can reverse it and use a signed challenge. **Make sure to encrypt the private key since someone could potentially steal it and compromise a user's data**

Or (I'm totally joking, but...) you could have them answer a series of questions, hash the text of the questions, and send that to the server :D

---

Have you tried Parse? http://parse.com It has built in authentication and you can store data about a user server-side. You could also use a SHA/MD5 hash of a user-provided username, for example.

Please note that if you're searching online and see any references to a device UDID or UUID as a unique identifier, **this method is deprecated** and sometime in the future Apple reserves the right to reject your app from the app store.

Comment: thanx for reply. ya i know this is the reason, why client is asking other way for authenticate. and application like of that i cant use username and password for authentication. so i am finding some other way.

Comment: thanks Mr.jack ..i got my answer. one more help i need . can you sugess me which algorithm i can use for it.

Comment: The Keychain Services iOS framework has built in keypair generation, or you can use CommonCrypto `<CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` if Keychain Services is too limited for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but this requires both iphone and server elements. In short this is a HUGE question. The 10,000 ft view is. Create an authentication app tied to a database that exposes an xml or json api. On load of your app display a view or a UI prompt, send the data from the view / prompt to the server for authentication, pass back a TRUE/FALSE response. Act accordingly.

Comment: thanx for reply.but i want something that i can pass for authentication. what i can pass for that? i dont want to pass username, pass, device id. client want something else.

Comment: You'll need something on the server side to authenticate against. Make an xml file full of unique strings and then distribute a string to every user, or store it in a MySQL table. Or have one string hardcoded in the device code and give that out. It all depends how secure it needs to be. Your questions seems a bit vague. If you give more specs on what you are securing we could probably help guide you more.

Comment: i want high secure this thing. if we pass simply that by proxy you can hack this and it can be change by that.

Comment: The only way to highly secure it is to SSL encrypt a user name password pair. And distribute said user names and passwords. Or build a service with Twillio in which u can request an authentication Id via text message. Then use the responding code as a secure id. This will require alot of server side code to generate these ids and store them, but then users can authenticate via the id they get texte'd